# Some Buttons are not clickable in Landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Problem is shown in picture , please go light on me , i'm not that experienced in android
but trying my best to do so...

[image]
Tried this in my Main.java:

```
package com.faisal.my_calculator;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
// all remaining imports here.

public class Main extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


// Buttons
Button btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree, btnFour, btnFive, btnSix, btnSeven,..., btnTan, btnExit;

    case R.id.three:

        if (y != 0) {
            y = 0;
            etDisp.setText("");
        }
        str = str.append(btnThree.getText());
        etDisp.setText(str);
        break;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    case R.id.add:
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etDisp.getText().toString())) {
            return;
        }
        operator = "+";

        if (x == 0) {
            x = Double.parseDouble(etDisp.getText().toString());
            etDisp.setText("");
        } else if (y != 0) {
            y = 0;
            etDisp.setText("");
        } else {
            y = Double.parseDouble(etDisp.getText().toString());
            etDisp.setText("");
            x = x + y;
            etDisp.setText(Double.toString(x));
        }

        break;
```

I tried for: 
appconfigchanges solution = it is not even in my AndroidManifest.xml,

Now to the layout part : In emulator all things are fully spaced on screen but when i run app below(2nd screen comes as a result not like on Emulator which i worked hard and adjusted its full screen) more when i run it on my LG_OG in landscape only starting three rows come on the screen o.O ....?  need help here as well ...!

If anything needed more i will post it....!(now almost all code i have posted) Again, be patient to your brother :)

Comment: why not put all the setClickListener on function onResume? and not screen layout related

Comment: this Didn't help buddy :/

Comment: do u have 2 layouts for land and port if so please post them.

Comment: i have but i cant put all that ... u know reason. buddy

Comment: since you have 2 layouts the question asked in both of the layouts there are similar names ?

Comment: yes definitely they have same name.

Comment: Terrible, terrible question... "I think listener is not getting called" -> then use breakpoints/logs in your listener method and you'll know. You posted a lot of code that couldn't possibly cause the problem, but does overwhelm the reader of the question. Last but not least, you are asking about a listener problem but also about your layouts not adapting to every screen : these are 2 very separate issues, you should have 2 separate questions. Please reformat your question, I'm voting to close this one.

Comment: @2Dee as i said i'm beginner and learning , why u got so tensed..? yes i sorted it out ..! please if you are so sophisticated that you can't go polite on novice ones and can't read lengthy codes then please do close the threads after seeing that a novice has posted it .! simple.

Comment: that's nice 2Dee how you left a vote down on my all created threads , that's very constructive.... use of high score , plz mods look into this.!

Comment: You're the one who's accusing others of being "tensed", "sophisticated" and downvoting all of your questions. Maybe you should take yourself, and everyone else, a little more seriously. Remember that this is a professional site. Being a novice doesn't mean you can talk back at people like that.

Comment: with all due respect , i'm sorry if i went wrong , but many others went through that code even guy with 50k votes and left a gentle and helping comment to solve problem only he found this thread as "terrible terrible question".... and after my 2nd last comment i got vote down to all my threads.! peace . take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , what a pain it was , as debugger is the best friend of programmer , i debugged it and it directly took me to the buttons which i didn't make in Landscape but were present in portrait so Eclipse doesn't like this and was causing my different buttons to stay idle but after putting those buttons in landscape xml now everything works all awesome...!

Now just layout make-up is remained as two buttons are running here and there when i run it.! :p

Thanks guys for your time...!

Answer (score 1):

Please don't handle any exception if it is not realy needed to handle. Remove your try catch while initializing the UI and setting clicklistener to buttons and check where your code is failing.

Second you don't need to handle UI changes on orientation change as it will be handled by android itself. This will be done like -on orientation change your activity will be recreated and your oncreate will be again called so set layout and initialize all the UI element in oncrete itself and remove unnecessary code from onConfigurationChanged method.

Comment: I removed try catch and i got a error "Unable to start activity Component info" , whose solution is to clean and refresh, worked for me. but now landscape mode is giving error (above mentioned).!

Comment: can you post your complete error for better understanding

Comment: So you have to keep in mind that you don't need to handle the error when it is not realy needed. It will help you in fixing issue at initial stage of coding itself. Always handle specific exception don't handle generic exception.

Answer (score 1):

Always check for the null value in suspected code
    if(btnDiv == null)
    {
        //condition
     }

Answer (score 0):

Add following code just before try

```
    if(btnDiv == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("Button are not initialized");
     }
```

if exception is thrown then your buttons are not initialized.